# How to showing alert to user when login failed in React native with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

There is `LOGIN` button which has `onPress = this.props.onPressLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password)` in component.

The `onPressLogin` in-directly called action generator, `loginAct`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onPressLogin: (email, password) => {
            dispatch(loginAct(email, password))
        }
    }
};
```

The `loginAct` is actually kind of **thunk**, which return async function and finally its callback generate action.

```
exports.loginAct = (email, password) => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:3000/login', { email: email, password : password })
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.data.result == 'success') {
                    dispatch(authUser(email));
                } else {
                    // I want to show alert to user.
                    dispatch(alertUser(response.data.message));
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                throw error;
            })
    };
}; 


alertUser = (alert) => {
    return {
        type: 'ALERT_USER',
        alert
    }
};
```

At this point I don't know how to alert user properly. Is this proper way? I do that if `ALERT_USER` action generated its reducer handle this

```
    case 'ALERT_USER' :
        return {
            sysAlert : action.alert
        };
```

And in component,

```
    if(this.props.sysAlert != ''){
        Alert.alert(
            'Alert title',
            this.props.sysAlert)
    }
```

This way looks like working but I am not sure proper way. After alert, the this.props.sysAlert is not empty, so every time when component moved the empty alert shown. I don't know how to set default to `this.props.sysAlert`.

Should I create `CLEAR_ALERT` action? so when Alert window disappear, then clean `sysAlert` in redux store? It is very complicated I think, Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Alert from React-Native. So you can do simply:

```
 alertUser = (alert) => {
   Alert.alert('Alert title', alert);
     return {
         type: 'ALERT_USER',
         alert
     } };
```

Or if you want to show the error message next to the inputs you can use a syntax like:

```
<Inputs />
{this.props.error && <ErrorMsg />}
```

Since you are using redux connect it will automatically update the `this.props.error`. In this case you need to map the state to the props too.